# Excel adding an ' to the beginning of all my cells (APOSTROPHE being magically added)

Tags: vba, excel

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WorksheetName").Cells.Range("A1:A1000000")
.Formula = formulavariable
.Value = .Value
End With
```

When Excel does .Value=.Value it adds an ' to the beginning of all the values. If I right click and paste as value it removes the '. The problem is this code is extremely efficient and takes less than 1 second when I try to remove the ' it takes forever to load all the cells.

Comment: I suspect your cells are being formatted as Text - try specifying `.Numberformat = "general"` before the `.Value = .Value`

Comment: @Rory The data is text, I tried changing the numberformat to general but it still gives me the apostrophe in front of each name. I can't copy and paste it away because there is too many cells... but if I individually copy and paste as value it removes the apostrophe.

Comment: @Rory okay this is strange, I tried the same exact formula on a different  column and it works without adding the magic apostrophe... I made sure the format on both columns are general. Is there some hidden formatting I am missing here? Also is there a way I can have it paste a value of nothing if it is nothing... it is replacing nothing with 0...

Comment: You need to share all of your relevant code. i.e. the bit where you set `formulavariable` would be helpful.

Comment: @guitarthrower just replace formula with ="abc" and I still get the same problem. My other problem is when it equals ="" it will replace it with a 0.

Comment: replace it with `="abc"` or `"=abc"`? They are very different when `.Formula` is being used. Also, instead of just changing the format, try to clear all formats from the ribbon (`Home` > `Editing` > `Clear` > `Clear Formats`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub testit()
    formulavariable = "=1+2"
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WorksheetName").Cells.Range("A1:A1000000")
        .Clear
        .Formula = formulavariable
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

If you wish to fill the cells with a *Null* then:

```
Sub FillWithNulls()
    formulavariable = Chr(61) & Chr(34) & Chr(34)
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WorksheetName").Cells.Range("A1:A1000000")
        .Clear
        .Formula = formulavariable
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to make ="" equal nothing instead of 0?